# Zookeeper error: Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: Len error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, appixia

We have a well configured zookeeper and kafka cluster nodes. The manual test for creation a topic and sending a message on that topic passed successfully. But when I run a test from a test equipment in order to create a topic with MQTT protocol, I receive:

```
Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: Len error 271056900
[myid:1] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client /192.18.0.1:15659 (no session established for client).
```

Can someone give me some hint on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are exceeding your `jute.maxbuffer`. Try to increase it. [Here](https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/150660/error-javaioioexception-len-error-in-zookeeper-cau.html) you can find some more information.

Comment: https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_4/setting-up-an-external-zookeeper-ensemble.html#configuring-jute-maxbuffer-on-zookeeper-nodes

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker-compose, this helps me:

```
environment:
  KAFKA_OPTS: -Djute.maxbuffer=500000000
```